# Downloaded my dataset combine from BigQuery to Google Sheets using Export, but only showed me 500 rows instead of the 3,745,465 rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I want to export some datasets I combined which results in 3,745,465 rows in total. When I get to Google Sheets it says only allows me to see 500 rows "preview." When I clicked on my columns filters, the system has 3,745,465 but when I downloaded it as an excel sheet it only gives me 500 rows only instead of the whole data.

The result I want is to get the whole row number counts not only the 500 rows preview.

Answer (score 1):

google sheets compared to bigquery is a small ecosystem. there are limits even cell limits. you are allowed to have 10 million cells per the whole spreadsheet. so if you have only one sheet with one single column you can have 10M cells which is equal to 10M rows (in theory). in reality, you will experience significant performance issues after like 30k rows and with ~ 80k you will be lucky if the whole spreadsheet won't crash.

Comment: Yes I understand that part, I am trying to export that whole data from BigQuery to R.

Comment: @Tails0298 did you try the BigQUERY > CSV > R perhaps?

Comment: No, I haven't used this or maybe can you explain to me how that works. Thank you

Comment: You'd just download it as a CSV from BQ instead of a Google Sheet.